# How to implement the observer pattern using async iterators in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm working on implementing the observer pattern in Python using asyncio and async iterators. The goal is to create a “change stream” where tasks can add changes, and other tasks can subscribe to these changes as asynchronous iterators. I'm trying to create an interface similar to [broadcast streams](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html) in Dart.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
from asyncio import Condition

class ChangeStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self._condition = Condition()
        self._change = None

    async def add_change(self, change):
        async with self._condition:
            self._change = change
            self._condition.notify_all()
    
    async def __aiter__(self):
        async with self._condition:
            while True:
                await self._condition.wait()
                yield self._change
```

Is this the best approach to implementing the observer pattern? Are there more efficient or easier-to-reason-about ways to implement this?

Edit: The goal here is that observers can see all changes from after they subscribe, but none of the changes from before they subscribe.

Comment: Would two consecutive changes both need to arrive at all subscribers? Or is it OK for a subsequent change to cause previous changes never to arrive? (an example where it matters is a chat interface, an example where it doesn't matter is a status indicator) Your current solution can cause race conditions where a new change overwrites a previous change before it was received by an observer. If you need observers to see all changes, using a Queue would make more sense.

Comment: @Grismar The goal here is that observers can see all changes from after they subscribe, but none of the changes from before they subscribe.

Comment: @Grismar My initial thought was that the lock in the Condition would be sufficient to prevent the race conditons, but I'm still not completely sure. How would you create a Queue with multiple consumers where all consumers recieve all changes from after they subscribe?

Comment: I've written an answer that I think works as you expect. Part of the problem is that the system needs to keep track of who has already received a message before moving on to the next one - I hope the answer below is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description and comment, it appears you're really looking for a Publish-Subscribe pattern instead of an Observer pattern. They are similar, but where Observers are typically known by the subject and get updates directly, in Publish-Subscribe, the publisher publishes to a bus (like your Stream) that tracks consumers that are interested in the data.

Here's an example with a `Queue`-based implementation, and some extra code to show how it all works - of course you could use the class differently, the `TaskGroup` is just one way of getting some tasks going:

```
from asyncio import Queue, TaskGroup, sleep, run
from random import random


class ChangeStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self._subscribers = []

    async def add_change(self, change):
        for queue in self._subscribers:
            await queue.put(change)

    async def __aiter__(self):
        queue = Queue()
        self._subscribers.append(queue)
        try:
            while True:
                yield (value := await queue.get())
                if value is None:
                    raise GeneratorExit
        except GeneratorExit:
            self._subscribers.remove(queue)


async def produce_changes(stream: ChangeStream):
    for i in range(10):
        await sleep(random() * 3)
        print(f"Add value: {i}")
        await stream.add_change(i)
    print("Done adding values, writing None to stream.")
    await stream.add_change(None)


async def consume_changes(stream: ChangeStream, name: str, start_delay: int):
    await sleep(start_delay)
    print(f"{name} starting...")
    async for value in stream:
        print(f"{name} received: {value}")
        if value is None:
            break


async def main():
    # create a stream, pass it to a producer task to publish to
    stream = ChangeStream()

    async with TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(produce_changes(stream))
        tg.create_task(consume_changes(stream, 'consumer 1', 0))
        tg.create_task(consume_changes(stream, 'consumer 2', 5))  # start after 5 sec


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Output (example, due to randomness):

```
consumer 1 starting...
Add value: 0
consumer 1 received: 0
Add value: 1
consumer 1 received: 1
Add value: 2
consumer 1 received: 2
consumer 2 starting...
Add value: 3
consumer 1 received: 3
consumer 2 received: 3
Add value: 4
consumer 1 received: 4
consumer 2 received: 4
Add value: 5
consumer 1 received: 5
consumer 2 received: 5
Add value: 6
consumer 1 received: 6
consumer 2 received: 6
Add value: 7
consumer 1 received: 7
consumer 2 received: 7
Add value: 8
consumer 1 received: 8
consumer 2 received: 8
Add value: 9
Done adding values, writing None to stream.
consumer 1 received: 9
consumer 1 received: None
consumer 2 received: 9
consumer 2 received: None
```